# 2 combobox working together

Tags: html, combobox

I have two comboboxes:
Enable monitoring: Yes/No
and
Operation mode: Client/Server

The default value of the first one is 'No' and the second should be hidden. When I change it to Yes, I want the second combobox to be visible. How can I do that?

```
    <tr>
        <td width="25%" class="titulos" nowrap>Enable monitoring:</td>
        <td width="75%" class="dados" nowrap>
        <select class="dados" name="proxyconf" onchange="showOptions ();">
        <option value="1" selected>No</option>
        <option value="2" >Yes</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="25%" class="titulos" nowrap>Operation Mode:</td>
        <td width="75%" class="dados" nowrap>
        <select class="dados" name="proxyconf" onchange="showOptions ();">
        <option value="1" selected>No</option>
        <option value="2" >Yes</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with Javascript.

Give the second option box an ID, and then use Javascript to show/hide it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showOptions() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("id_of_second_box");
  elem.style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

You can pass in the option box to the function by reference if you like, and there are many different ways of showing/hiding elements using Javascript and CSS, but something along the lines of the above should help.

Comment: This would work if the second one was hidden beforehand. But for cross-browser compatibility, you'd have to hide it with JS.

Comment: That's true - you could hide it with CSS but then as you say someone without JS enabled would never see it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/qtHc3/ (the example uses jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript:

```
 function showOptions(elem){
  if(elem.value == "2"){
    document.getElementById("second").style.visibility = "visible";   
  }else{
   document.getElementById("second").style.visibility = "hidden";      
  }
}
```

And the first combobox:

```
 <select class="dados" name="proxyconf" onchange="showOptions(this);" id="first">
    <option value="1" selected>No</option>
    <option value="2" >Yes</option>
 </select>
```

And the second one:

```
  <select class="dados" name="proxyconf" onchange="" id="second" style="visibility:hidden">
    <option value="1" selected>No</option>
    <option value="2" >Yes</option>
  </select>
```

But this may not be cross browser compatible so check carefully.